# Only joining rows where the date is less than the max date in another field

Tags: sql

Let's say I have two tables. One table containing employee information and the days that employee was given a promotion:

```
Emp_ID     Promo_Date
1          07/01/2012
1          07/01/2013
2          07/19/2012
2          07/19/2013
3          08/21/2012
3          08/21/2013
```

And another table with every day employees closed a sale:

```
Emp_ID     Sale_Date
1          06/12/2013
1          06/30/2013
1          07/15/2013
2          06/15/2013
2          06/17/2013
2          08/01/2013
3          07/31/2013
3          09/01/2013
```

I want to join the two tables so that I only include sales dates that are less than the maximum promotion date. So the result would look something like this

```
Emp_ID     Sale_Date     Promo_Date
1          06/12/2013    07/01/2012
1          06/30/2013    07/01/2012
1          06/12/2013    07/01/2013
1          06/30/2013    07/01/2013
```

And so on for the rest of the Emp_IDs. I tried doing this using a left join, something to the effect of

```
left join SalesTable on PromoTable.EmpID = SalesTable.EmpID and Sale_Date 
< max(Promo_Date) over (partition by Emp_ID)
```

But apparently I can't use aggregates in joins, and I already know that I can't use them in the where statement either. I don't know how else to proceed with this.

Comment: Create a subquery with the max(promo_date) and join then two

Comment: What database do you use? Oracle, Mysql,???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum promotion date is:

```
select emp_id, max(promo_date)
from promotions
group by emp_id;
```

There are various ways to get the sales before that date, but here is one way:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where s.sales_date < (select max(promo_date)
                      from promotions p
                      where p.emp_id = s.emp_id
                     );
```

Comment: This answer did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is right on! Alternatively, you could also do a `inner join` to a subquery to achieve your desired output like this:

```
SELECT s.emp_id
      ,s.sales_date
      ,t.promo_date
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT emp_id
          ,max(promo_date) AS promo_date
    FROM promotions
    GROUP BY emp_id
    ) t ON s.emp_id = t.emp_id
    AND s.sales_date < t.promo_date;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7849/4/0)